# Recipe for backcountry ice cream?

Tags: backpacking, food

In honor of [National Ice Cream Month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Ice_Cream_Month), does anyone have a good back-country ice cream recipe they could share?

Bonus points for ones that don't require ice (ice field, glacier, etc.)

Comment: Back country ice cream recipe  --  1: Do a nice hike in the back country.  2: Convene at ice cream place afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

As a kid we made "backpackers ice cream" something like this...

- 1 package Dream Whip (topping mix)
- 1 package Jell-O pudding
- Powdered milk (enough to make 2 cups milk as required by the pudding mix)
- 2 cups Water (enough to make the milk)

Mix the above in a pot or baggie and chill as well as you're able - a cold stream works.

I doubt you'll ever get an ice cream headache from this, but it was a fun treat.

Answer (score 4):

The way I see it, you have two options:

1. Buy some astronaut ice cream.
2. Bring/find some ice and [make ice cream](http://teachnet.com/lessonplans/science/plastic-bag-ice-cream-recipe/) in a plastic sandwich bag.

I bet you could easily replace the ice in the standard 'ice cream in a bag' recipes with snow. You might have some trial-and-error to get the proportions right, but I bet it would work.

Personally, I would just bring some astronaut ice cream and sit around the camp site telling stories about the space program. But that's just me.